# Why can't I draw a smaller bitmap into a larger canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

I have a created a custom view (Display) that accepts non view Icons that create semi static (rarely changing) bitmaps. The idea is to pass a number of Icons to the Display to be printed to its canvas. My problem is that I cannot get the Display to actually draw the Icons bitmap into its canvas.

The code below is a working example of what I have. (by working I mean executes properly, not that it prints what I want it to)

```
public class AndroidTestoActivity extends Activity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
        Display tv = new Display(this); 
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200, 200));
        fl.addView(tv);
        setContentView(fl);
    }

    public class Display extends View {
        Paint vPaint = new Paint();
        Icon item = new Icon();

        public Display(Context context) {
            super(context);
            vPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            vPaint.setColor(0x0ff000000);
            setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        }

        @Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.scale(200, 200);
            item.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawLine(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, vPaint);
        }
    }

    public class Icon {
        Bitmap myImage;
        Paint mPaint = new Paint();

        public Icon() {
            myImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(myImage);
            c.scale(50, 50);
            c.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, mPaint);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

This code should be printing out a line from upper-left to lower-right and draw a 50px diameter circle from 0,0 to 50, 50. Instead all I get is the line. However, if I print the bitmap to a file, the file outputs exactly what it should.

Does any one have a clue as to what is happening?

**EDIT**
To clarify my question, I am creating a Bitmap that is significantly smaller than the DisplayView. When I attempt to draw the bitmap into the DisplayView, the bitmap is not at all what I drew and never scaled appropriately. Why is the canvas not drawing the Bitmap properly?

**UPDATE**
In the Diplay's onDraw method, I moved the line `items.onDraw(canvas);` to before `canvas.scale(200, 200);`. Now the test circle draws correctly. What is such a simple change doing to completely ignore drawing the circle the pervious way?

Comment: `scale()`, `translate()`, `skew()`, and any others that [mention](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) the "current matrix" work on a [transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) - it's not _quite_ as simple as doing them one after another to get what you want (sometimes you want the reverse!).  But I don't remember enough at the moment to answer _why_ moving that line works in this particular instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I @MartinAsenov was mostly correct. What I ended up needing to do was draw all of my cached bitmaps *before* (or after if saved and restored) I scale the canvas and draw normally. As for scaling the canvas, I believe that is still necessary (all of my other widget scale to their width and height before drawing with no issue).

Here is the final working test activity.

```
public class AndroidTestoActivity extends Activity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
        Display tv = new Display(this); 
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200, 200));
        fl.addView(tv);
        setContentView(fl);
    }

    public class Display extends View {
        Paint vPaint = new Paint();
        Icon item = new Icon();

        public Display(Context context) {
            super(context);
            vPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            vPaint.setColor(0x0ff000000);
            setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        }

        @Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            item.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
            canvas.scale(getWidth(), getHeight());

            canvas.drawLine(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, vPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    public class Icon {
        Bitmap myImage;
        Paint mPaint = new Paint();

        public Icon() {
            myImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(myImage);
            c.scale(50, 50);
            c.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, mPaint);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(myImage, 50, 50, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got a reason for the down vote? I don't mind, but I can't learn from what I did wrong if you don't tell me.

Answer (score 0):

looking through your code I think the main problem is that you assume coordinates to be 0f..1f but truth is 0f..width / 0f..height - float is used to have subpixels

Comment: Where do you mean? I can draw a line just fine using 0-1.0f in the DisplayView, so where is the difference between drawing in the views canvas and the bitmap created off view?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess will be that the circle becomes too big (scaling it 200x) and thus its coordinates get negative (i.e top left corners is (-5,-10)). The android system won't draw views with negative coordinates (if you want to achieve this you need to override the onMeasure() method)

Comment: I don't think the `View#drawBitmap(Bitmap, float, float, Paint)` call resizes the bitmap. If I'm correct there, how is the circle becoming too big? Are its dimensions not directly related to the size of its Bitmap, which in this case, is 50x50px?

Comment: In the constructor of the Icon class you are drawing a circle with 25 pixels radius which is OK. In the ondraw method however you are getting the canvas from the onDraw() method of the Display class. This canvas has been scaled 200 times meaning that anything drawn onto it will appear 200 times bigger. Now since your circle is drawn in the top left corner of the screen and its radius is 25pixels it will get 200*25 = 5000 pixels. Now I guess you understand why your view will get outside of the screen.

Comment: I award you with the bounty and a because tour answer pointed me in the correct direction, however is was not the direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're slightly confusing how canvas works (and it's not intuitive, so, it's easy to confuse). The way you're invoking Canvas, with the Bitmap as a param, it winds up treating the bitmap as the thing that's being painted onto, so, you're constrained by the dimensions of the bitmap. 
If you were to create a Canvas without a param (an empty canvas) and THEN draw a bitmap into it, it then doesn't actually alter the Bitmap, it just draws on the canvas. In that situation you can draw the bitmap anywhere within the rectangle and draw a circle around it (or whatever else you want).

Also, you can override the onDraw method and collect *its canvas (which it hands you when it calls the callback), you then draw whatever you want onto that canvas... That's the canvas that actually shows up on the screen, and that's the easiest way to get access to it.

Comment: I think I follow what you are saying, but could you post a small example?

Comment: I'm on my phone, atm, so, it's hard to type out code examples (speech recognition works nicely for stuff like this comment).  You're very close to what you want to do. Work with the onDraw method, and use *that canvas to draw into, rather than drawing onto your bitmap as you're doing in your Icon method.